# Fabric : ignore env.hosts when using -H option

Tags: python, fabric

When using command `-H` one can specify hosts on the command line.

Let say by defaut you have set a `env.hosts` variable with a list of hosts. But sometimes, you need to apply your functions on only one or two of thoses hosts and you need to use `-H` .

How do you proceed to ignore `env.hosts` when using this argument ? I don't find any info about it. Is it the good way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate `env.hosts` only when it was not specified as a command line argument like:

```
env.hosts = env.hosts or ['host1', 'host2', 'host3']
```

This way when a CLI argument `-H`/`--hosts` is set, `env.hosts` already contains a value when the fabfile is loaded and you're not overwritting its value.

As stated in [documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/execution.html#order-of-precedence), hosts list specified from CLI are the latest in the precedence order, thus may be overriden by others.